# Exeception = unexpected token: * near line 1,

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am having exception listed below, any helps are appreciated.

```
Exeception = unexpected token:* near line 1, COLUMN 603 [
SELECT
  a.putwall_id,
  a.work_control_number,
  a.lpn,
  a.putwall_cube_id,
  a.date_created,
  a.last_activity_date,
  b.location,
  b.work_zone,
  b.product,
  b.quantity_required,
  b.quantity_processed,
  (b.quantity_required - b.quantity_processed) AS quantity_cut
FROM
  work_type_headers a, work_type_lines b
WHERE
  UPPER(a.TENANT_ID) = ?
  AND UPPER(a.COMPANY_ID) = ?
  AND UPPER(a.FULFILLMENT_CENTER_ID) = ?
  AND a.work_type = 'PICK'
  AND a.status <> 'COMPLETED'
  AND a.work_control_number = b.work_control_number
  AND b.quantity_required <> b.quantity_processed
  AND b.status = 'ASSIGNED'
  AND a.lpn <> ' '
  AND NOT exists(SELECT 
                   *
                 FROM
                   work_type_lines c
                 WHERE
                   c.work_type = 'BATCHPUTWALL'
                   AND c.status <> 'COMPLETED'
                   AND b.product = c.product)
  AND NOT exists(SELECT 
                   *
                 FROM 
                   work_histories d
                 WHERE 
                   d.work_control_number = a.work_control_number
                   AND d.work_history_code = 'COMPLETED'
                   AND d.task = 'PUTWALLPUTPULL')
ORDER BY
  a.last_activity_date]
```

I have no exception running the SQL in Oracle SQL Developer.

```
SELECT
  a.putwall_id,
  a.work_control_number,
  a.lpn,
  a.putwall_cube_id,
  a.date_created,
  a.last_activity_date,
  b.location,
  b.work_zone,
  b.product,
  b.quantity_required,
  b.quantity_processed,
  (b.quantity_required - b.quantity_processed) AS quantity_cut
FROM
  work_type_headers a, work_type_lines b
WHERE
  UPPER(a.TENANT_ID) = 'XC3'
  AND UPPER(a.COMPANY_ID) = 'COMPANYABCD'
  AND UPPER(a.FULFILLMENT_CENTER_ID) = 'DC1'
  AND a.work_type = 'PICK'
  AND a.status <> 'COMPLETED'
  AND a.work_control_number = b.work_control_number
  AND b.quantity_required <> b.quantity_processed
  AND b.status = 'ASSIGNED'
  AND a.lpn <> ''
  AND NOT exists(SELECT 
                   *
                 FROM
                   work_type_lines c
                 WHERE
                   c.work_type = 'BATCHPUTWALL'
                   AND c.status <> 'COMPLETED'
                   AND b.product = c.product)
  AND NOT exists(SELECT 
                   *
                 FROM 
                   work_histories d
                 WHERE 
                   d.work_control_number = a.work_control_number
                   AND d.work_history_code = 'COMPLETED'
                   AND d.task = 'PUTWALLPUTPULL')
ORDER BY
  a.last_activity_date;
```

Comment: OK, you told us where you are NOT having the exception... but your forgot to tell us where you DO have the exception. Please enlighten us.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the root cause for the exception.
By changing the query listed below, the query ran without any exception.
When you have select statement in your SQL, you should use `createSQLQuery` instead of `createQuery`.

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                            .createQuery(GLOBALCONSTANT.PutWall_GetPendingProduct);
```

to

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                            .createSQLQuery(GLOBALCONSTANT.PutWall_GetPendingProduct);
```

Now the final code:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                            .createQuery(GLOBALCONSTANT.PutWall_GetPendingProduct);
query.setParameter(0, COMMONUTIL.setDbDefaultString(tenant_id.trim()));
query.setParameter(1, COMMONUTIL.setDbDefaultString(company_id.trim()));
query.setParameter(2, COMMONUTIL.setDbDefaultString(fulfillment_center_id.trim()));
pendingProductBeanObjList = query.list();
```